# WAMP Server seems to deny access

Tags: apache, http, wamp

I'm trying to set up a WAMP server, after mucking around for most of the day I finally have it up with two virtual hosts and a test page on each.

I now have an issue with the CSS JS not loading.

If I try to move up a folder level to retrieve the Files WAMP seems to block access to these files ( if I open the .html file without WAMP the Scripts load fine ).

```
<link href="../Global/Scripts/css/Visual_Map.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If I move the 'Global' folder into the same directory then it all works fine:

```
<link href="Global/Scripts/css/Visual_Map.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But of course then I have to copy and Paste my 'Global' making it, well not so Global.

Is there a setting somewhere in WAMP to allow access to this folder?

httpd-vhosts.conf:

(Global is located at C:/wamp/www/Global)

```
<Directory C:/wamp/www>
    Order Allow,Deny  
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\Concepts"
    ServerName produce.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\EN"
    ServerName help_page.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is

```
http://help_page.local/
```

You are trying to go above the root to the parent directory of `/`.

There is no parent directory. You are at the very top.

The directories in the URL map on to filesystem directories which are the filesystem root, but that doesn't matter because the `../` is evaluated by the *client*, not the server.

It would also be a serious security matter if things were the other way around: `http://example.com/../../../../../../../etc/password`.

If you want a directory to be accessible, then you have to give it a URL.

You could do that by using [an `Alias` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias), creating a symbolic link, moving the directory you want to access, or hosting it with a different hostname and using an absolute URI.

Comment: I couldn't get the Alias working, but I set-up a new v.host and works fine. - Thanks